# How to remove files from /web folder in Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

I'm using

`$model->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model,'file');`

and

`$model->file->saveAs($model->file->baseName.'.'.$model->file->extension);`

to save file.

I'm saving the file only because I cannot get the absolute file path using `realpath()` which I'm saving in the database. Once I'm done writing it to database I want to delete/remove the file. Is there a proper way to do this? I would also like to know if there is a better approach to do what I'm doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PHP unlink

```
  unlink( '.' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $model->file->baseName.'.'.$model->file->extension);
```

Comment: I've added the code but the file is still there. The file gets saved with red-only access rights. Could that be the problem?